# Regex with multiple queries

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to test multiple conditions with a single regex.

My Regex:

```
^(?=.*no+\s+or+\s+no+\s+maybe).*
```

Sample test string :

> Yes or No
>
> Maybe yes or no
>
> Maybe no or no
>
> No or no Maybe
>
> No maybe or No

When executed, it only matched "**No or no Maybe**".

The query should match as long as it finds "**NO**", "**OR**", "**NO**" and "**MAYBE**" (case insensitive) on the string

(Notice that there are 2 **NO**s. Treat the second **NO** as a separate variable. It should not match a string unless there are 2 **NO**s.)

Aside from "**No or no Maybe**", it should still match "**Maybe no or no**" and "**No maybe or no**".

I have also tried this one :

```
^(?=.*(?=.*no)(?=.*or)(?=.*no)(?=.*maybe)).*
```

Apparently it also matched **Maybe yes or no**

Comment: How you're selecting output. a bit explanation please

Comment: @CodeManiac I am not sure if I understand your comment correctly, so I edited it to "Matched" instead.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/eRrBW9/1/ check this you want something like this ?

Comment: @CodeManiac, yes something like that. but "yes" is not a constant variable and I would prefer a different method instead

Comment: That is what i asked in first comment on what rules you're selecting your output. without knowing them can't tell you exact answer. i have seen a pattern of not including yes.

Comment: @CodeManiac ahh I understand. Basically, the query should match as long as it finds "no or no maybe" on the string.

Comment: Do you mean like this? `^.*(?:no maybe|maybe no) or no.*$` https://regex101.com/r/TWKBaF/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird it should still match "No or No maybe". Again, should match as long as it finds "no", "or", "no", "maybe" on the string.

Comment: So then it should find 4 out of 5 from your example data right instead of 2 because they all match No and Maybe. Or is it case sensitive?

Comment: @Thefourthbird i have posted 3 outputs from my original thread. If you are talking about "Maybe yes or no" then it should not be included as it only contains 1 no.

Comment: @GunjackSparrohw So like this then https://regex101.com/r/dVkXna/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird thanks for the update. unfortunately, "maybe no or no" was not matched on your regex. I have updated my thread to avoid further confusions.

Comment: @GunjackSparrohw Then you could use several lookarounds https://regex101.com/r/lQHUqe/1

Comment: @GunjackSparrohw Did that work for you?

Comment: @Thefourthbird hi there. thank you for the update! i am now trying to work out the use of the query on different scenarios (different set of words).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use lookarounds to check for your requirements and use word boundaries `\b` to prevent the words being part of a longer match:

```
^(?=.*\bno(?! maybe\b))(?=.*(?<!\bmaybe) no\b)(?=.*\b(?:no maybe|maybe no)\b)(?=.*\bor\b).+$
```

That will match

- `^` Assert the start of the string
- `(?=.*\bno(?! maybe\b))` Positive lookahead to assert `no` not followed by maybe using a negative lookahead
- `(?=.*(?<!\bmaybe) no\b)` Assert that there is a `no` not preceded with maybe
- `(?=.*\b(?:no maybe|maybe no)\b)` Assert that the string contains `no maybe` or `maybe no`
- `(?=.*\bor\b)` Assert that the string contains `or`
- `.+` Match any character except a newline 1+ times
- `$` Assert the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1lmlCi/1)